# Dynamic Apache Camel Output Route

Tags: apache-camel

Hi i want to compute a dynamic output route using apache Camel. I receive a bunch of files in a folder location, based on its contents i want to move the file to dynamic output folder. The name of the ouput folder will be constructed based on the input content of the file. How do i acheive it.

The Following piece of code read the files, processes them, but i am not sure how to set the value of ${foldername} based on the contents of the file

```
   from("file:D:\\camel\\input\\one?recursive=true&delete=true")
            .process(new LogProcessor())
            .to("file:D:\\camel\\output\\${foldername}")
```

Please assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom processor to construct the foldername and insert into a header.

```
public class DirectoryNameProcessor implements Processor {
    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) {
        Message in = exchange.getIn();
        // Get the contents of the processed file
        String body = in.getBody(String.class);
        //Get the original file name
        String fileName = in.getHeader("CamelFileName", String.class);
        // Perform your logic
        in.setHeader("foldername");
    }
}
```

Then in your route you could access the newly created foldername-header:

```
.to("file:D:\\camel\\output\\${header.foldername}");
```

Comment: Or have a POJO method that returns a string like `${my.getFolderName}`

Comment: Oops sorry, the code you provided does not work  , i have to use the recipientList(header("foldername")), instead of the to command

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can use the dynamic to endpoint `toD`.
http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html#MessageEndpoint-DynamicTo

It would look like:

```
from("file:D:\\camel\\input\\one?recursive=true&delete=true")
        .process(new LogProcessor())
        .toD("file:D:\\camel\\output\\${foldername}")
```